# Expressjs vhost manager

Tags: node.js, express, vhosts, express-vhost

I need to find a way to manage subdomains using code.

For exemple, I want to have an API on mydomain.com that will manage running vhost. A request to API.mydomain.com/create would create vhost for a new subdomain (the code would be something like app.vhost.create, for exemple).

**Is there a way to dynamically manage vhost on running app using code?**

(If the question is not clear please tell me, English isn't my main language).

If it's not possible, I would like to do something similar but instead of subdomains, using routers.

If it's not possible, I would like to do something similar but instead of subdomains, using routers.

Comment: Please, provide example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Alaindeseine exemple: get request to mydomain.com/list would return a list of running vhost. The code would be something like app.vhost.list. a post request to mydomain.com/create would create a new vhost and the code would be something like app.vhost.create().